# UDP hole punching with Mobile device on cellular network

Tags: sockets, networking, udp, p2p, hole-punching

I have local server running in my local network.I want to enable external devices to make request to my local server in this case i am testing with android phone on cellular network.For this I am trying to do UDP hole punching.First I am sending http request from the mobile device to public server to give the public  server mobile device's information(IP and Ports) so that i can use them to punch a UDP hole in my local server.But the problem is i am getting NAT public IP & public Port and only local IP of the mobile device but not Local Port.And I just learned that cellular network wont let you use mobile local ports.The question now is how would i accomplish UDP hole punching in this case? If there is anything that i mis-stated please correct me.Thank you in advance